# Empty UITableView scrolls slowly on iPhone 4 running ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uitableview, ios7

Ok, I'm at a loss.  I have a tableview that works fine in iPhone 5/5S, but can only manage 4 fps on an iPhone 4.  I've tried every trick in the book to optimize the cells (opaque, misaligned frames, no blending, render uilabels into images, static cell heights, etc), but it didn't even move the needle.  Thinking that the root cause could be somewhere else, I decided to strip out all my custom cell code so that `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns an empty (but re-used) UITableViewCell, and even that runs slow...  I've tried profiling the app while scrolling the tableview, but nothing stands out at all.  The only thing that seems suspicious is that if turn on CoreAnimation's `Color Hits Green and Misses Red`, the status bar will constantly flash between green and red as I scroll the tableview.  This leads me to believe that the status bar is being redrawn every frame (or every couple of frames), but even hiding the status bar didn't improve the fps by much (maybe 4 -> 7).

So.... I'm at a loss.  Anyone out there experience something like this and can point me in the right direction?

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:__inboxCell];
    if (! cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:__inboxCell];
    return cell;
}
```

---

Here's when I run a time profiler and get around 6 fps:

[image: Time Profiler with System Libraries]

When I remove the system libraries, it's pretty useless.  If I keep scrolling for a few minutes, the % of Parent for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will greatly exceed that of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (which obviously only runs once).

[image: Time Profiler without System Libraries]

Comment: What are you doing in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?  This is basically always the answer to slow-scrolling `UITableView`s.

Comment: try to create a sample project with Master-Detail template to see whether it is still slow on iPhone4

Comment: @nhgrif I ripped out all my code, so it was basically dequeuing a reusable cell and returning it immediately...

Comment: You say "basically".  Is this what you're actually doing?

Comment: @scorpiozj good idea, but given that I see plenty of other apps with perfectly normal table views, I just assumed that performant tableviews in ios7 are still possible...  I'm curious if this will help me track down what's killing my CPU

Comment: @nhgrif haha yea, everything's ripped out.  I'm returning blank cells.  Still slow...  I'm hoping that means my cell creation/reuse code is well optimized and that my problem is elsewhere. :)

Comment: You can use instrument to track why it is slow. And just like @nhgrif refers, how do you implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is important.

Comment: I don't care what you're returning.  I care about the implementation of the method.  This method is called EVERY TIME a new cell scrolls into view.  If you sort an array with 10,000 elements three times in three different ways, and then `return [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];`, your table is going to scroll slow, because before it can execute that return statement it has to do a lot of other stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close on "lacking sufficient information to diagnose problem" until the full `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation is included in the question.

Comment: Click the edit button.

Comment: Where is the output from Instruments showing the percentage of time spent in each section of your code?

Comment: @RoboticCat is that what you're looking for?  I'm happy to screenshot any other profiles that you think makes sense.

Comment: That's what I was looking for - and something is amiss in OHinboxViewController. A couple of questions: Are you using Storyboards and Prototype Cells or XIBs? Are you using a custom UITableViewCell subclass? What other work are you doing in layoutSubViews (anywhere)? What other work is going on in the table view `delegate` and `dataSource` methods? Are you sure cells are being reused (is memory usage constantly increasing)?

Comment: @RoboticCat good questions. OHInboxVC is a UITableViewController subclass that is initially set up in a storyboard (but only nav bar buttons are customized, everything else is vanilla). At this point, of testing, I'm simply returning blank non-subclassed UITableViewCells. Height is static, number of rows still come from a FRC (but this call doesn't show up anywhere in the time profiler's list). Memory is not increasing.

Comment: OK - I'm at a loss then. As an aside, if you are using prototype cells then your `if (! cell) {...}` code is not required as prototype cells in Storyboards are guaranteed to be non-nil.

Comment: @RoboticCat haha, thanks for thinking about it!  I'll tell you if I ever find anything.

Comment: @scorpiozj I tried an empty Master-Detail app and the tableview runs fine so I'm definitely screwing something up!  Any other ideas on how to track down the culprit?  Haha, I guess I'm going to start commenting out more and more pieces of code until I find it...

Comment: In most cases this will happen in case of "wrong code" in `cellForRowAtIndexPath `delegate. For your code, try to set breakpoint on `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` to see whether the cell is nil. If it is always nil, it must has sth wrong.

Comment: +1 I have same kind of issues on my project. please give me answer for this question

Comment: @Mr.T- Have you found any solution to this problem, as i am going through the same. Thanks

Comment: @HarshThakur Sorry, I never solved this one